# Windows Python 3.9, pip, vscode not working correctly tried every tutorial

Tags: python, windows, command-line, visual-studio-code

I've gotten this to work relatively easy on my Mac I with django but for some reason Windows has been a heartache.

the problem is that in the console I can only get py to start executing python.
python and python3 do not work whatsoever

and also I can't get pip to install either because the py command won't execute it but python and python3 just open the windows store.

I've installed python to the path with the installer and I made the location of the file C:\Python\Python39

changed the hierarchy in the PATH in user variables and system variables to where python is at the top in both.
[image: I put scripts is at the top now but I've played around with it and also added python.exe into the path]

I've edited the vscode settings [image: Default and user settings with python.pythonPath]

I've also turned off the App execution aliases. That did nothing.

I'm at a complete loss so if any one has any advice I'd be so appreciative.

Comment: Im not entirely sure if this is what you're asking, and I see that you've already accepted an answer, but I'll put this out here anyways. When I used to use windows, I also had trouble with pip, and I had to use pip like this: `py -m pip install requests`. Not sure why this is how it is but that's what I needed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial helped me make pip working when I started programing

https://youtu.be/28eLP22SMTA

Comment: So I did get it to work inside a virtual enviroment!